# ArangoDB, Java, Velocypack error trying to deserialize a DBEntity

Tags: java, spring-data, deserialization, arangodb

I'm using SpringBoot 1.5.4.RELEASE, ArangoDB java driver 4.5.0, Arango Spring Data 1.1.5

I'm getting this error when retrieving an object.

```
com.arangodb.velocypack.exception.VPackParserException: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.arangodb.springframework.core.convert.DBEntity
```

I can't find the root cause yet (still looking) but I can see where the error is being thrown, in the class VPack there is this method

```
private <T> T createInstance(final Type type) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
  final T entity;
  final VPackInstanceCreator<?> creator = instanceCreators.get(type);
  if (creator != null) {
    entity = (T) creator.createInstance();
  } else if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    entity = createInstance(((ParameterizedType) type).getRawType());
  } else {
    entity = ((Class<T>) type).newInstance();
  }
  return entity;
}
```

but the type being passed in is the *interface* `com.arangodb.springframework.core.convert.DBEntity`.  There is no creator for this, and it is not a parameterized type, so newInstance is called.  This of course fails.

This seems to originate from `ArangoTemplate` in the find method.  Here is where DBEntity.class is being passed in.

```
  @Override
  public <T> Optional<T> find(final String id, final Class<T> entityClass, final DocumentReadOptions options)
      throws DataAccessException {
    try {
      final DBEntity doc = _collection(entityClass, id).getDocument(determineDocumentKeyFromId(id),
        DBEntity.class, options);
      return Optional.ofNullable(fromDBEntity(entityClass, doc));
    } catch (final ArangoDBException e) {
      throw translateExceptionIfPossible(e);
    }
  }
```

I am trying to create a test that will produce this on demand.  If I succeed I will post here.

thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should normally not happen, because there exists a [VPackDeseralizer for DBEntity](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/blob/master/src/main/java/com/arangodb/springframework/core/convert/DBEntityDeserializer.java). Do you maybe have overridden `AbstractArangoConfiguration.arangoTemplate()`? In this case you have removed the needed configuration of the underlying driver.

Comment: Thank you, yes in fact I had overridden the arangoTemplate() - in order to set some customer conversions that I don't think I need.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you need customer conversions you can override `AbstractArangoConfiguration.customConversions()`